# I require help - python, I don't understand it, using findall function, no error given

Tags: python, regex

The program runs with no errors, i have the file checker.txt in the same file as the .py file, nothing is output in the shell window, no "it worked" (irrelevant data = im using aircrack-ng to output into a text file to then read the text file with python, to then turn on an LED light)

```
from re import findall
booleanvar = False
while(booleanvar == False):
    file1 = open("checker.txt", "U")
    file2 = file1.read()
    file1.close
    search = findall ("2K([A-Z]* [A-Z]*)! ", file2)
    if(search == "KEY FOUND"):
        booleanvar = True
        print "it worked"
```

Comment: `findall` returns a `list`. Therefore, no list will ever equal the string literal `'KEY FOUND'`.

Comment: Also, rename `booleanvar` to `found` and write `while not found:`; readability counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cyber commented, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of matched strings (or lists depend on the number of captured groups).

The list is treated as a truth value if it contains any item (otherwise false value). So just use it as a predicate.

```
....
search = findall("2K([A-Z]* [A-Z]*)! ", file2)
if search:
    booleanvar = True
    print "it worked"
```

If you don't need all the matched strings, but only check whether it matches at least one sub-string or not, use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) which returns matched object or `None`. (the matched object is also treated as a truth value when used as a predicate).

```
search = re.search("2K([A-Z]* [A-Z]*)! ", file2)
if search:
    booleanvar = True
    print "it worked"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all, so much, I forgot that findall makes a list of results. I simply changed if search[0] == (what i want) and it worked :D

Thanks again